# Is it possible to run a module's setup function while importing it in a TC39 'ES6' import?

Tags: javascript, commonjs, es6-modules

In CommonJS one can run:

```
const module = require('module')(API_KEY)
```

In the various ways [TC39 / 'ES6' modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) (inverted commas as there are are more modules writted in ES6 using CommonJS than this syntax), how can I do the same?

It looks like this isn't possible, ie my only option is:

```
import moduleSetup from "module";
const module = moduleSetup(API_KEY);
```

Answer (score 2):

> ie my only option is

Correct, at least for now.

It may be that the [dynamic import proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) will let you do something like the `require` call, but it's at Stage 3 right now. (Of course, if you use them for this, the import won't be statically-analyzable anymore...)